# java web server sending continuous response to browser but not closing the socket when client is closed

Tags: sockets

I am making a `server` side program using `socket` programming in `java`,
which handle `multiple request` from the client.
Here client is `browser` not a client program.
`Server` accept request from `browser` and process request using `Thread`.
in response Web Server sending Continuous `data` to browser as a `streaming`
Am getting problem
when user close the `browser` or change the tab or minimize the `browser`.Then
Server is not able to detect browser states on `socket`.

why Data is continuously sending by `server` program to `socket` when browser is minimize.
How we can detect browser states on java socket means tab,close or minimize.

i want to know
How `Apache tomcat` detect whether the browser is open or close or tab change in browser.

Comment: Which version of Tomcat are you using?

Comment: You can send a heart beat to check if the client socket is still active or not

Comment: @Kamahire am making server program using java socket programming